# Do normal region restrictions apply when playing PS1 games on PS3?

Tags: ps3, ps1

I got my PS1 while living in the US and I live in EU now. Will my US PS1 games work on a PAL PS3 or do normal region restrictions apply?

Comment: Your aware only the old ps3's play ps1 games right?

Comment: @Ender: That's false. All PS3s play the same set of PS1 games, which is almost all of them.

Comment: I was under the impression that the newer models of Ps3 were NOT going to be backwards compatible. Sony said this at one point although I am unable to source such.

Comment: @Ender: You can't source it because it's wrong. Most models of PS3 cannot play any PS2 discs; of the remaining models, some have significant compatibility issues. All models play most - and the same set of - PS1 discs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PS1 games are region locked, so you won't be able to play them on your PAL PS3.

Sources:
http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090515104048AA4nkOp
http://www.eurogamer.net/forum_thread_posts.php?thread_id=140751

Answer (score 1):

Only the Classics downloads from the PSN are region-free, so if you create a USA account on your PAL PSN, the PS1/PS2 games from the USA PSN will work, same goes for Japanese games.